# Sending Emails using a Lambda Function, NodeJS, Mailgun, and testing Params in Postman

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, postman, mailgun, netlify

I am learning all of this as I go. The goal is to simply send an email using variables, and here's the code that I have so far in *test.js*:

```
const mailgunSdk = require('mailgun-js');
const apiKey = 'MAILGUN_API_KEY';
const domain = 'MAILGUN_DOMAIN';
const mailgun = mailgunSdk({
    apiKey,
    domain
});

exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {

    //console.log(event.body)
    //const data = JSON.parse(event.body)

    let response
    try {
        /* Send email to recicipent */
        response = await mailgun.messages().send({
            from: 'Reginald Fromington <mg@fromaddress.com>',
            to: 'bobloblaw@gmail.com',
            subject: 'Hello',
            text: event.messageText
        })
    } catch (e) {
        //console.log('Err', e)
        return {
            statusCode: e.statusCode || 500,
            //body: JSON.parse({
            //  error: e.message
            //})
        }
    }

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            result: response.message
        })
    }
}
```

Using Postman, I can actually get a message in my inbox if I have `text:` as a string, such as  `text: 'Thank you for your email'` if I'm running the function without any params. However, if I want to use a variable, I have no idea how to pass them into the function. I've tried `text: event.messageText`, `text: response.messageText`, `text: mailgun.messageText`, and every possible combination of variables that I could imagine to pull from.

Most of the documentation that I could find is outdated or doesn't address this issue. I also don't really know how to google this issue because again, I'm new to all of this.

Thanks,
-Andrew
[image: Postman Screenshot]
*Attempting to pass parameters into Lambda Function*

Comment: In your screenshot, you are setting your variable in the Postman **headers** tab. I think you should rather use the **body** tab and then uncomment your lines about `event.body` in your lambda function code.

Comment: If I uncomment `//const data = JSON.parse(event.body)`, I get a `Function invocation failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` error. if I try using the `body.messageText` variable, I get a `Function invocation failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` error.

Comment: Mmh, maybe check if the Content-type header is application/json in your postman headers tab or that your payload, in the body tab is send as json. Otherwise uncomment youf first console.log and you'll possibly have a clue in your lambda logs.